# Matlab - Select rows given a condition

Tags: matlab, select, cell, conditional-statements

I have a cell variable (Size:2639516x12, Bytes:3863876744, Class:cell) and I want to make a selection, considering the first row. So for instance if I have

```
A:
1997 FD 89
1997 GD 65
1999 FDK 87
2010 UY 123
```

I would like to get

```
B:
1997 FD 89
1997 GD 65
```

To get to cell A I use the following code:

```
% Transfer csv file to matlab    
Data_file = fopen('Data.csv'); 
Data = textscan(Data_file,'%q %q %q %q %f %f %f %f %s %f %f %f %s %f %s %f %s %f %f %f %s','delimiter',',','headerlines', 1);
fclose(Data_file);

%Convert numbers into strings
F_5=Data{:,5};
F_6=num2cell(Data{:,6});
F_7=num2cell(Data{:,7});

%Get the first 4 numbers within variable F_5
F_5A=max(0,fix(log10(F_5)+1)-4);
F_5B=fix(F_9./10.^F_5A);

%Convert number into string
F_5C = num2cell(F_5B);

%Create new cell A w/ variables I want
A=[F_5C Data{:,1} Data{:,2} Data{:,3} Data{:,4} F_6 F_7];
```

Comment: You should use tables if you have a recent enough version of Matlab. Otherwise, check into cellfun.

Comment: Cold you show what the cell variable looks like, please. is (1) `A ={1997 FC 89}` or (2) `A={{1997} {FD} {89}}` ? How would you want the output to be? As in (1) or (2)?

Comment: You can use `ismember` for this

Comment: @kkuilla Of course, `A=[{1997} {FC} ...]`. Maybe this will help   `>> whos TABLE_FA Name: TABLE_FA, Size:2639516x12, Bytes:3863876744, Class:cell`

Comment: Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @user3557054 wait `A=[{1997} {FC} ...]`??? Are you sure it's not more like `A = {1997,  'FD',  89; 1997...}`?

Comment: @Dan I used this `[` type of brackets but I can change them and see if it works! I have been using this because it has been working to join different cell variables into one cell only. But it may be totally wrong!

Comment: @Dan I used `{` now and the difference is that I get a `1x12 cell`, instead of `2639516x12`. And I am not sure if will be able to do my calculations like this, but I will try! Thanks

Comment: @user3557054 Please post the code you're using to create the matrix

Comment: @user3557054 if size of `A` is  `2639516x12` ,  then try `B = A(cell2mat(A(:,1))==1997,:)`

Comment: @Nishant Have you checked the output of `B`? I thought of the same solution. It might be my version but I don't get a cell array out of that command.

Comment: @kkuilla I have checked it on matlab r2011a and I am getting proper output.

Comment: @Dan can you please tell me how can I post the code in a proper way without being in the question itself. I tried in the comment but it was a mess. If you still want to see it. :) Thanks!

Comment: @user3557054 I think there is no problem in posting the code in the question under an **EDIT** title. In that way it will be more informative to the viewers

Comment: @user3557054 Just **edit** your question as Nishant has indicate. There is a link for editing underneath the tags at the bottom left of your question

Comment: @Dan and Nishant thank you. I will do it now. I am always learning here. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using logical indexing

```
B = A(cell2mat(A(:,1))==1997,:);
```

Thanks to excaza for mentioning that values may not be rounded

If the year values are not properly rounded (i.e some cells have value as 1996.999999 or 1997.0001) then use

```
e = 0.001 %\\some small value
B = A(abs(cell2mat(A(:,1))-1997)<e,:);
```

Comment: Worth noting that this may not always match when it should if the years are not stored as integers.

Comment: @excaza if they are stored as strings or uint then you are right, but I think as per question they are stored as integers or float.

Comment: Like I said, if they're stored as floats they may not always match.

Comment: @excaza If they are stored as 1997.0000 then they will match but if they stored like 1996.99999999, then yes, they will not match, but that depends on how OP is generating this cell. I just assumed that they will be round numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to extract specific rows based on the first column of a.

```
b=a(~cellfun('isempty',(cellfun(@(x) find(x==1997),a(:,1),'UniformOutput',false))),:);
```

Here is how it works:

```
a = 

    [1997]    'FD'     [ 89]
    [1997]    'GD'     [ 65]
    [1999]    'FDK'    [ 87]
    [2010]    'UY'     [123]

b=a(~cellfun('isempty',(cellfun(@(x) find(x==1997),a(:,1),'UniformOutput',false))),:);

b = 

    [1997]    'FD'    [89]
    [1997]    'GD'    [65]
```

Comment: Looks like a nice solution but how did you create `a`?

Comment: I have saved the data into a tab delimited .txt file and imported the data into 'a' using a custom data import function (found online) @kkuilla.